# Json Parse Error. Can not Deserialize from Object Value

Tags: json, rest, spring-boot

There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).

JSON parse error:

```
Can not construct instance of javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?); 

nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?) at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@da18a91; line: 1, column: 622] (through reference chain:
```

Below is my code:
Here is my controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = { "/api" })
public class TestController {

    /*
     * @Autowired BeanTest bean;
     */

    private final static QName _PersonalNameTypeGivenNames_QNAME = new QName("http://sita.aero/iborders/evisa/Common/V1", "GivenNames");
    private final static QName _PersonalNameTypeFamilyName_QNAME = new QName("http://sita.aero/iborders/evisa/Common/V1", "FamilyName");

    @RequestMapping(value="/getBeanTest", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getTestBean() {
        BeanTest bean = new BeanTest();
        List<BeanTest> beanTest = new ArrayList<BeanTest>();
        final List<JAXBElement<String>> jaxbElements = new ArrayList<JAXBElement<String>>();
        JAXBElement<String> jaxbElementGivenNames = new JAXBElement<String>(_PersonalNameTypeGivenNames_QNAME, String.class, BeanTest.class, "Gaurav");
        jaxbElements.add(jaxbElementGivenNames);
        JAXBElement<String> jaxbElementFamilyNames = new JAXBElement<String>(_PersonalNameTypeFamilyName_QNAME, String.class, BeanTest.class, "Chhimwal");
        jaxbElements.add(jaxbElementFamilyNames);
        bean.getContent().addAll(jaxbElements);

        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(bean,HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

My Entity is

```
public class BeanTest {

    protected List<JAXBElement<String>> content;


    public List<JAXBElement<String>> getContent() {
        if (content == null) {
            content = new ArrayList<JAXBElement<String>>();
        }
        return this.content;
    }

}
```

I am calling this service from another rest api. Getting this error while calling the service:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = { "/api" })
public class SpringRestController {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder;

    @Autowired
    public Environment env;



    @GetMapping(value = "/getApplicationTest", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getApplicationTest() {

        RestTemplate restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.build();

        BeanTest obj = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:1010/api/getBeanTest",
                BeanTest.class);
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(obj, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you need a no-arg constructor. Maybe

Comment: What do you expect as answer? Could you provide some codes?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (you get a badge!), Read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) & [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) & [How to create a Minimal, Complete & Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)